# Convergence to Dirichlet function is not uniform

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Let $r_{1},r_{2},...$ a sequence that includes all rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Define $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=r_{1},r_{2},...r_{n}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

this sequence converges($lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$) to dirichlet function in $[0,1]$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Question: Is the convergence uniform?

This question is taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813145/does-this-sequence-of-functions-converges-uniformly-to-dirichlet-function), below is my attempt to the question:

Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}.$
    For any $N \in \mathbb{N},$ choose $x = r_{N + 1}.$
    Then $|f_N(x) - f(x)| = 1 \geq \varepsilon.$ Hence the sequence of functions does not converge uniformly.

Can anyone check my proof?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct. Your reasoning basically shows

$$ \sup_{n} |f_n (x) - f(x) | = 1 \nrightarrow 0 \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ n \rightarrow +\infty $$
hence the convergence can't be uniform.